Screenshot of the Week #118 - Constructive Buildings
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 118th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Neon1024's screenshot from assassins-creed-valhalla won with 14 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-06-24, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-07-01, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Constructive buildings
Show us the best buildings or infrastructures you can find or build!
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Why "constructive buildings"? Are the buildings supposed to be constructive, and, if so, how? (Ah, I see now that it's the original phrasing of the proposal. Yet still I wonder why.)

@Joachim no idea, I used the theme as it was

does it have to be an exterior shot, or can internal construction count?

@MissMisinformation it's not stated anywhere that it has to be exterior, so feel free to submit

Just played the demo of the wonderfully pleasant and soothing tiny-glade:


A cliffside apartment I built at the Starlight Drive-in settlement - fallout-4


How many beds/baths? :-)

@LoreFriendly Two apartments with 1 (Double) bed each, a commercial opportunity upstairs, and defense along the northern side. Potential renters are welcome to use the public facilities, and if you count the pond in the middle of Starlight, it has a pool too! :P

But do you sell guns?

@Joachim Yes! We currently have a commercial tenant specialising in weaponry

I have first and last months rent ready in caps, I knew saving up all my nuka cola caps was smart.



deus-ex-mankind-divided

When I read the theme title, I first thought this was about buildings that construct something, maybe like an automated factory. That reminded me of Cubehamster's "missile factory" in Minecraft, which builds multiple flying machine and sends them off. And that then reminded me of something similar in John Conway's "Game of life", which… may be a game…? This is a cellular automaton with very simple rules: Any white pixel that has 2 or 3 white pixels in the 8 spots around it stays white, all others turn black. At the same time, all black pixels that have exactly 3 white pixels around them turn white, all others stay black. These simple rules lead to very complex and interesting behaviour, they are even Turing-complete. Numberphile has a good video about it, with the inventor, John Conway. And on CodegolfSE, people have even created Tetris in Game of life!

The pattern shown here is included in the default set of patterns when you install the program "Golly", so this is a bit of a cheat, since I did not invent it myself, but at least the screenshot is mine. And I really like this game/automaton/program, so I wanted to see it featured in this competition. What you see here is one end of "linear-propagator-p237228340", which is a machine that takes in a very long string of basically binary input (in the shape of lots of tiny 3×3 pixel "gliders" in a row with gaps in between) and acts similar to a 3D printer (but in 2D) that prints… itself! So the binary data is like the DNA of the printer head. If you let this run for hundreds of millions of steps, you end up with lots of copies of the starting pattern above each other. It is really fun to watch, I recorded a very laggy video here. (For some reason the program has extreme lag spikes when OBS is running, so I sped up the video 4×.)

Freaking awesome! ✨

It reminds me, I read a bit of trivia about Conway. Apparently, he was a mathematician who was disappointed by the fact most people would remember him only for his game of life. I think he recently (not so recent anymore) passed away because of covid.

@Clockwork Yes, relevant Numberphile videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8kUJL04ELA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsecAiJDI8s

@Clockwork it recalled me of infinitely marvelous works of Zachtronics, and relatively similar case as with Conway, probably, I believe that only a few know that Zach's work called Infiniminer inspired and evolved Minecraft. It's also mentioned in book called Zach-like. Ave genius! Ave indeed! Related: https://www.zachtronics.com/zach-like

The Experimental Gardens, from my minecraft-bedrock-edition adventure map "This One Takes the Cake":

Image resized to 50% using an online tool, as the original exceeded 2 MB
